# How do I mirror a object without the mirror modifier?

Tags: 3d-view

[image: Kitty]

My cat-human hybrid I'm making needs a right ear and it needs to be mirrored.

Comment: What's the reason for not being able to use a mirror modifier?

Comment: I'm new to this and in other programs, I use you need to install mods so I thought it would be like that with blender.

Comment: There isn't need to install anything to use Mirror modifier or any modifier, just open Modifiers tab in Properties editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you don't want to use a Mirror Modifier, you could nevertheless use it and apply it afterwards by pressing "Apply" after you're done modeling.

[image]

Or you go into Edit Mode, delete half of your mesh (depends on which axis you want to mirror, in this case I guess it's the X-Axis), then press <kbd>W</kbd> and select "Symetrice". There are different options when you open up the toolbar (<kbd>T</kbd>), so play around with the axis mirror type.

Attention: Be sure that the origin of your model is located at the cutting edge, otherwise it will cut it where the origin is located at. To move the origin, select the cutting edge in Edit Mode, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, select "Cursor to Selection", the go into Object mode, select your mesh and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and select "Origin to 3D Cursor". **And make sure to apply any rotation or scale changes before doing so.**

[image]

Comment: TYSM ~! \[^w^]/

Answer (score 2):

This works both in Object and in Edit mode.

1. Place the 3D cursor where the mirror axis origin would be (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will place it at the origin (position $0,0,0$)
2. Change Pivot center for rotation or scaling to be 3D cursor (or press <kbd>.</kbd> (dot) on the keyboard)
3. Duplicate the object or part of mesh you want to mirror (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (or find command *Object > Mirror Mesh > Mirror*) and then select the axis you want to mirror the duplicated object along (in interactive mode press <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> on the keyboard). Click left mouse button to confirm.

In order mirroring to work correctly in Object Mode you have to Apply Scale and Rotation on the object first.

Comment: Note that Ctrl+M mirrors by scaling selection to -1 which leads to inverted normals so it's best to recalculate them after executing Mirror